# Trying to use dictionary and function, but recieving a TypeError

Tags: python, function, dictionary

```
living_places = [
  {"structure": "house", "price":700000},
  {"structure": "apartment", "price" : 200000},
  {"structure": "dump", "price": 30000}
]
```

I'm trying to compare user input parsed to integer and then using that to "buy" a structure from living_structures. Around the buy variable is where the TypeError occurs: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

```
def client_money(place):
  money = int(input())
  for prices in place:
    buy = money - place["price"]
    if buy >= place["price"]:
      print(f"client purchased living_places{['structure']} and has {buy} money left")
    else:
      print(f"{buy}, client does not have enough money...")

client_money(living_places)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Does your code not work properly or cause an error? Please clarify.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?

Comment: Thanks for wanting to help, i'll delete the question and try again to clarify

Comment: @newbieZ No need to delete, just edit this one.

Comment: How do i do that btw? can't find a delete button..

Comment: okay i'll do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of mistakes in your code.

1. It doesn't make any sense to say `for prices in place:` because you're iterating through each building, not each price.
2. `buy = money - place["price"[0]]` is wrong. For one thing, `place` should be `building/prices`, and also `"price"[0]` makes no sense. `buy = money - building["price"]` is sufficient.
3. In `buy`, you've already calculated the difference between `money` and `building["price"]`. Instead of `buy >= place["price"]`, just do `buy >= 0`.
4. Finally, improve your f-string. Just do `{building['structure']}`.

Below is the full corrected code:

```
living_places = [
  {"structure": "house", "price":700000},
  {"structure": "apartment", "price" : 200000},
  {"structure": "dump", "price": 30000}
]

def client_money(place):
    money = int(input())
    for building in place:
        buy = money - building["price"]
        if buy >= 0:
            print(f"client purchased {building['structure']} and has {buy} money left")
        else:
            print(f"client does not have enough money for {building['structure']}...")

client_money(living_places)
```

Comment: @newbieZ No problem. If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score -1):

Integers can be accessed like any other variable in a dictionary. To access the price of place you can do

```
place["price"]
```

you also need to specify the name of the dictionary when accessing it, so for accessing 'structure' you would need to do

```
place["structure"]
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. `place` refers to the `living_places` list, so you can't access `["price"]` or `["structure"]`.